# Does the original German version of Fontane's Tay Bridge poem contain the same literary references?

Tags: poetry, translation, german-language, theodor-fontane

In [this English translation](https://www.bartleby.com/177/96.html) of Theodor Fontane's poem "Die Brücke am Tay" (here translated as "The Bridge by the Tay", elsewhere also as "The Tay Bridge"), I noticed a couple of lines which are clearly intended, *at least in this English translation*, to evoke thoughts of older literature:

- > “When shall we three meet again?”

  The opening line of the poem, also the opening line of Shakespeare's play *Macbeth*.
- > What the hand of man hath wrought!”

  Repeated twice in the poem, [seems to be](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/What_hath_God_wrought) a reference to [the Bible](https://www.kingjamesbibleonline.org/Job-12-9/).

In the English translation, these are obviously references to well-known quotes. **Were these references equally clear in the original German version, or are they an invention of the translator?**

---

I found [another translation](https://www.railscot.co.uk/articles/A_German_View_of_the_Tay_Bridge_Disaster/) which preserved the Macbeth quote exactly, but gives the Bible quote as:

> Man’s handiwork is dust and ash.

However, this could mean either that the original German has no such biblical reference, or that *this* translator wasn't well-versed enough in German biblical quotes to recognise it as such. So it's not conclusive evidence in answering my question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The original German text begins with the following lines:

> »Wann treffen wir drei wieder zusamm'?« 
>     »Um die siebente Stund', am Brückendamm.« 
>        »Am Mittelpfeiler.« »Ich lösche die Flamm'.«

Compare this with the opening lines of the translation by Dorothea Tieck, first published in 1832 (in: *Shakspeare's dramatische Werke*. Übersetzt von August Wilhelm Schlegel. Ergänzt und erläutert von Ludwig Tieck, Bd. 9. Berlin: Georg Andreas Reimer, 1832):

> Wann kommen wir drei uns wieder entgegen, 
> Im Blitz und Donner, oder im Regen?

The first line asks, "When will the three of us meet [each other] again?" Fontane's "zusamm'" (a shortened form of "zusammen" that rhymes with "Brückendamm") is strictly speaking redundant but linguistically correct; see [zusammentreffen](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/zusammentreffen) in Wiktionary. Dorothea Tieck's *Macbeth* translation uses "entgegen" (see [entgegenkommen](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/entgegenkommen) in Wiktionary) instead of "zusammen" to achieve a rhyme with "Regen" (rain). [0]

For a translation that uses the same rhyme as Fontane's poem, see [Wilhelm Jordan's translation](https://books.google.at/books?id=j4xMAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA6&hl=de&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=3#v=onepage&q&f=false), first published in 1865:

> Wann kommen wir Dreie wieder zusammen
> Bei Regen, Donner und Wetterflammen?

However, even for readers who weren't familiar with Wilhelm Jordan's translation, the reference to *Macbeth* should have been clear to German readers, especially since the lines that follow carry on the allusion, although less directly.[1]

The lines "“A bauble, a naught, / What the hand of man hath wrought!” correspond with the following German lines:

> »Tand, Tand, 
> Ist das Gebilde von Menschenhand.«

[Tand](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Tand#Noun) means "trifles, trinkets". The word appears to come from the phrase [Nürnberger Tand](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spielzeug#Industrie) (literally "trinkets from Nürnberg"), which referred to toys produced and sold in Nürnberg, where the "toy industry" took off in the fifteenth century. The translation as [bauble](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/bauble#Noun) does not appear to preserve this connection with toys.

Job 12:9 (in German: Hiob 12:9) reads as follows in [Luther's Bible translation of 1545](https://newchristianbiblestudy.org/bible/german-luther-1545/job/12/) [2]:

> Wer weiß solches alles nicht, daß des HERRN Hand das gemacht hat,

Literally: "Who does not know that the LORD's hand made all this."

What remains from this line from Job/Hiob is "Hand". If the line in the poem was intended as an allusion to Job, Fontane's "Tand" contrasts strongly with God's creatures in the Bible book.

---

[0] For comparison, here are a few other German translations that existed during Fontane's lifetime.

- By [Christoph Martin Wieland](https://www.projekt-gutenberg.org/shakespr/macbeth/macbth11.html) (1760s):

> Wenn kommen wir drey uns wieder entgegen,
> In Donner, Blizen oder Regen?

- By [Gottfried August Bürger](https://books.google.de/books?id=-WsHAAAAQAAJ&hl) (1783):

> Na! sagt, wo man sich wiederfind't
> In Donner, Bitz o'r Schlackerwind?

- By [Friedrich Schiller](https://www.projekt-gutenberg.org/shakespr/macbeth2/mac2101.html) (1801),

> Wann kommen wir drei uns wieder entgegen,
> In Donner, in Blitzen oder in Regen?

[1] Several online versions of the poem even cite "When shall we three meet again (Shakespeare: Macbeth)" as a kind of motto, e.g. on [www.martinschlu.de](https://www.martinschlu.de/kulturgeschichte/neunzehntes/vormaerz/fontane/balladen/brueckeamtay.htm), [Levrai.de](https://online-lernen.levrai.de/deutsch-uebungen/balladen/bruecke_am_tay/01_ballade_brueck_am_tay.htm) and [Phantasus.de](http://handmann.phantasus.de/g_brueckamtay.html) but not on [Deutschland-Lese](https://www.deutschland-lese.de/index.php?article_id=541). If that quote was part of the version that Fontane published, the reference would have been blatantly obvious.

[2] For comparison I also cite a modern version of the same line in the ["Luther 2017" translation](https://www.bibleserver.com/LUT/Hiob12):

> Wer erkennte nicht an dem allen, dass des HERRN Hand das gemacht hat,

Literally: "Who does not recognise in all of this [the animals and plants in the preceding lines] that the hand of the LORD made them".

Comment: Did those German translations of Macbeth and the Bible exist in 1916 when Fontane's poem was written? (I'm not sure what "Luther 2017" means; is it a translation done in 2017, or just a 2017 edition of an earlier translation?)

Comment: @Randal'Thor I assume "Luther 2017" is a modernised version of Luther's 16th-century translation, which I now cited in my updated answer. I have also replaced the *Macbeth* translation with one that has an identifiable translator; the so-called Schlegel-Tieck translation remained the standard Shakespeare translation for many decades and was reprinted well into the twentieth century.

Comment: And after the edits you have my upvote :-) One other thing worth noting: according to [this page](https://www.railscot.co.uk/articles/A_German_View_of_the_Tay_Bridge_Disaster/), the Macbeth quote (in English) is used as a header (epigraph?) on the original German version, but I haven't checked the original version to verify that claim.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Among the German versions I have checked, most use that Macbeth quote. I'll have to wait until the lockdown ends to check a more authoritative text in the library.

Comment: The cited German Macbeth is the standard one by Dorothea Tieck (1799-1841).  It is (or was, once) a shock to Germanophone children, to learn that their favorite playwright "Sha ke shpay ar re" was not in fact German.  I suppose Fontane's poem was inspired by the Tay Bridge disaster of 1879, so Tieck's Macbeth would have been available to him when he wrote it.

Comment: There' more translations of Macbeth. To give an authoritative answer it would be necessary to check all of them (or at least the ones popular at that time).

Comment: @user151413 Of course, there are [more translations of *Macbeth*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deutsche_%C3%9Cbersetzungen_von_Shakespeares_Werken), but the Schlegel-Tieck translation of Shakepeare's plays was the standard for many decades and the version that readers in the German-speaking world would be most familiar with. (And the allusion to *Macbeth* is not in doubt anyway.)

Comment: @Tsundoku Sure. I just think this is a caveat with the answer. Is it clear that Schlegel-Tieck was *the* translation at the time the poem was written?  I'm just searching and bumped into https://www.projekt-gutenberg.org/kraus/sprache/chap019.html, which among others presents a translation starting with **"Sagt, wann treffen wir drei zusammen"**, *much* closer to the poem. (Though I still need to figure out what this source is, still in the middle of it ... )

Comment: (For now, this looks like Karl Kraus' translation, so maybe *he* copied from Fontane, but maybe he also used a less well known source?)

Comment: Then again, [Jordan's translation](https://books.google.at/books?id=j4xMAAAAcAAJ) **"Wann kommen wir Dreie wieder zusammen"** pre-dates in an is pretty close to Fontane.

Comment: @user151413 That's a good find; i have added it, together with three other German translations.